# Running cron per hour?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am writing a cron in java to run per hour. I am using Java Quartz framework.

Is this valid `0 0 0/1 * * ?` schedule to run per hour?

I am using Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression looks correct

```
0 0 0/1 * * ?
```

This works as well

```
0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *
```

http://www.cronmaker.com/